# MySQL - Servicio inicia y después se detiene en Windows

Tags: mysql, windows

hace unos días estaba lidiando con la velocidad y eficiencia que mi base de datos MySQL tenía, me encontré que era posible optimizar la velocidad de mi base de datos con solo habilitar el cache en el archivo `my.ini`. Sabiendo esto modifiqué el archivo `my.ini` y añadí estas 3 líneas:

```
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_size = 10M
query_cache_limit=256k
```

Una vez estas 3 líneas habían sido añadidas reinicie el servidor MySQL para que aplicaran los cambios.

Fue en este momento cuando me apareció esta alerta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y bueno, no he podido hacer que el servicio MySQL inicie otra vez.

**Cosas a saber del archivo `my.ini`:**

- Antes de hacer esta modificación el archivo `my.ini` ya había sido modificado una vez sin problemas.
- En la modificación anterior el `innodb_buffer_pool_size` fue ajustado a `3G`
- El archivo fue en ambas ocasiones modificado con el Bloc de Notas.
- El servicio MySQL ya había sido reiniciado 2 veces el mismo día desde `Servicios`.
- Al revisar el codificado/encoding del archivo desde el Guardar como del Bloc de Notas aparece nada más como UTF-8 (hay una opción de UTF-8 con BOM debajo)

---

**¿Alguna solución?**

Gracias de adelantado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el cache en las versiones recientes de Mysql ya no esta funcional.
En caso de que no estés modificando el cache y te da error cambia el encoding del archivo `my.ini` a UTF-8.

Espero que a alguien le sirva :)